# npm install takes forever, says I am behind a proxy

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to install different packages using `npm 8.19.2`. For example yarn

`sudo npm install --global yarn`

All I get is

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1823:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-08T20_14_13_653Z-debug-0.log
```

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. According to this: http://www.amibehindaproxy.com/ I am not behind a proxy. I do not understand why I should be either. In fact, I don't know what it is.

```
node --version
v18.12.1
```

My goal is to get started with react. First step is to just run `npx create-react-app my-app`. But that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`wget` was also slow, then I found this [Slow wget speeds when connecting to https pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94074/slow-wget-speeds-when-connecting-to-https-pages).

Updating the network settings and disabling IPv6 did the trick.

[image]